# Create a click-to-drag user interface in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-interface

I've been working with WPF at work for the past 6 months, and I've grown to understand and like xaml. Now I'm beginning a side project that's very unlike the business applications I'm used to designing, and I'm wondering if Silverlight might be a good match.

It's a little like a family tree (not exactly, but close enough) where users create and add nodes. I want the bulk of the UI to be taken up by a click-to-drag area that displays the tree, allowing the user to pan and zoom, and hopefully also allow for interaction when a user clicks on a node.

Are there any built in controls in Silverlight that support this type of interaction? Has anyone worked on or seen something in that vein? I just want to know if I'm barking up the right tree so I can decide if it's worth my time to learn more about Silverlight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a drag and drop application for work and it does work well. Silverlight is a great environment for these types of interfaces. However, if you want to reach a larger audience (iPad, phones, tablets, etc), it would be worth your time to look into the HTML5 drag and drop. I haven't yet, but I'm sure there are some good examples out there. It really depends on your target audience.

The approach I took was to define behaviors that can be attached to any element. I got started from [Bruce Wayne's example](https://github.com/indexzero/bruce-wayne).

There is some intriguing examples using the RX, but I don't have a good handle on it yet, but here is a [Jesse Liberty example](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/02/11/reactive-drag-and-drop-part-1/).

If you have access to Telerik, you could use their controls. [Here is a good demo](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DragAndDrop/TreeToGrid).

Here is a blog on [zooming in Silverlight](http://silverlightedweb.blogspot.com/notify-NotifyUserWarning?aHR0cDovL3NpbHZlcmxpZ2h0ZWR3ZWIuYmxvZ3Nwb3QuY29tLzIwMDcvMTEvem9vbWluZy1pbi1zaWx2ZXJsaWdodC5odG1s).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of third party controls I am aware of that might be relevant:

http://www.silverdiagram.net/Projects/SilverDiagram.aspx

http://visualizationtools.net/default/productsoverview/graphite/